# Rails 3 and PDFKit, how can I convert an HTML file into a landscape orientation PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I can convert HTML pages into PDF documents well. The problem is, I don't know how to convert the HTML file into a landscape orientation PDF. Is there a way to set that in the controller?

From the controller...

```
def pdf_customer_shipments
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @shipments = Shipment.where("customer_id = ? AND status = 'Open'", @customer.id)
  render :layout => 'pdf'
end
```

Answer (score 9):

In case this helps, I am using PDFKit and can render the pdf in landscape using:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "my_page.html.haml")
    kit = PDFKit.new(html, :orientation => 'Landscape')
    kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/stylesheets/views/pdf.css"
    send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "some_name.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf')
    return # to avoid double render call
  }
end
```

I got the orientation part from here: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/12

Answer (score 6):

You need a meta tag in you html file:

```
...
<head>
  <meta name="pdfkit-orientation" content="Landscape"/>
</head>
...
```

Then the PDF is in landscape orientation.

Comment: This was perfect! In my middleware initializer I need to leave the default as Portrait, but this allows me to override it to Landscape on a page by page basis.

Answer (score 0):

PDFKit should accept options for wkhtmltopdf, so you should be able to render in landscape mode by using this:

```
def pdf_customer_shipments   
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])   
  @shipments = Shipment.where("customer_id = ? AND status = 'Open'", @customer.id
  render :layout => 'pdf', :orientation => 'Landscape' 
end
```